# Installing scikit-learn on Mac os x

Tags: scipy, scikit-learn

Is there a binary for installing scikit-learn on mac os x 10.6/10.7? Or an easy way to install scikit-learn? I already installed numpy, scipy, matplotlb and tested that they are working as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There are binary distributions that include scikit-learn:

- [Canopy](https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/)
- [Anaconda](http://continuum.io/downloads)

If you already have numpy / scipy and the XCode Command Line Tools installed then `pip install scikit-learn` will probably work by building it from source. This is the way I usually do it (on my own version of Python 2.7 installed with HomeBrew). Installing SciPy with pip used to be problematic on older versions. I don't think I had any issue as of SciPy 0.12 though.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way in mac os x is using pip:

```
sudo pip install -U scikit-learn
```

don't forget `sudo`!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to install `scikit-learn` easily. Run the folloowing command in a console :

```
pip3 install -U numpy scipy scikit-learn
```